# my navbar is not responsive on s3 mobile bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

in every mobile it shows same like this image

[image]
HTML:

```
    <div class="wrap">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top "  >
    <div class="container">
      <a href="indexf.php" class="navbar-brand"> <img src="image/logo3.png"  height="30px" alt=""></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active ">
            <a href="index.php"  class="nav-link ">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a href="#aboutus" onclick="href='index.php#aboutus'"; class="nav-link">About Us</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a href="#service" onclick="href='index.php#service'"; class="nav-link" >Services</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a href="CLients.php"  class="nav-link">Our CLients</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a href="#authors"  onclick="href='index.php#authors'"; class="nav-link">Our Team</a>
          </li>
           <li class="nav-item active">
            <a href="prodect.php"  class="nav-link">products</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a href="contactits.php" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">

            <!-- Button trigger modal -->
            <a href="contactits.php" class="btn nav-link active" style="background-color: transparent;border-radius: 11px;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
border-color: lightgray;">+92-42-35791029</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: it is not responsive with the mobile specially nav bar every thing else is ok

Answer (score 0):

This must be the browser version installed on your S3. Or it's not a browser that's supported by Bootstrap 4.

Update the browser and everything will be fine.

Comment: my fiend also check this there is also same problem so what is the main solution is some thing wrong with code ?